# How can i add a back button to dissmiss a modal screen in react-native-navigation(V1) on ios

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-navigation

i want to add a back button to a modal screen which dismisses the modalscreen in ios . Like default behaviour of modals in android.I use react-native-navigation(V1)

Comment: Please, post the code you're trying with, or at least the piece where you're opening the modal

Answer (score 0):

Use `Navigation.dismissModal(this.props.componentId)` to dismiss current modal. 
Place this button wherever you want to trigger it.

```
<Button
      onPress={() => Navigation.dismissModal(this.props.componentId)}
      title="Back"
      color="#841584"
/>
```

Comment: is there anyway to use the navigatorButtons to dismiss the modal